# iText - Need a solution for running a pdf form scripts programmatically

Tags: javascript, .net, itext

We are building a solution to fill in programmatically a PDF form with XFA with iText and .Net. A brief presentation of the solution: we need to update the xfa with our data but before that we need to run jave scripts to update the form fields. We've kept trying to find a solution to this issue in the iText docs, but nothing so far. Is there anyone out there who can help.

We can also pay for it, if necessary.

Really appreciate any feedback.
All the best and stay safe,

We extracted all events, scripts from XFA PDF on Acrobat reader. After adding the js, it has only read-only properties.

Comment: Your question is not clear. And besides I wouldn't build any solution on XFA since it is proprietary and dead (deprecated). And then javascript? I wouldn't use that either...

Comment: The Itext is providing a solution for updating an XFA form. Our problem is with dynamic forms based on pdf events - buttons and checkmarks. For this part we are looking for a solution.

Comment: As I said - bad idea / wrong solution. You might ask the guys from iText they offer commercial support for their PDF lib.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've been trying to get in touch with iText but for all their numbers and office i get only voice mail. Is there any other solution that could solve our problem?
Thank you for the support and appreciate your help.

Comment: You can contact iText support via this page https://itextpdf.com/support.